# De/Serializing LocalDateTime with akka-http

Tags: scala, akka-http

I am trying to add support for serializing and deserializing LocalDateTime in akka-http. I'm a little confused by the following error:

> Error:(42, 20) could not find implicit value for parameter um:
>   akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.FromRequestUnmarshaller[SomeData]
>             entity(as[SomeData]) { evt => complete(StatusCodes.Created) }
>
> Error:(42, 20) not enough arguments for method as: (implicit um:
>   akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.FromRequestUnmarshaller[SomeData])akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.FromRequestUnmarshaller[SomeData].
>   Unspecified value parameter um.
>             entity(as[SomeData]) { evt => complete(StatusCodes.Created) }

What an I missing in the following code? I pasted my code into the minimalist sample from the Akka-http documentation. I am running Akka-http 10.0.6.

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import scala.io.StdIn
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import spray.json.{DefaultJsonProtocol, JsString, JsValue, JsonFormat}
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route

final case class SomeData (dateTime: LocalDateTime)


trait JsonSupport extends SprayJsonSupport with DefaultJsonProtocol  {
  implicit val eventDataFormat: JsonFormat[SomeData] = jsonFormat1(SomeData)

  implicit val localDateTimeFormat = new JsonFormat[LocalDateTime] {
    private val iso_date_time = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME
    def write(x: LocalDateTime) = JsString(iso_date_time.format(x))
    def read(value: JsValue) = value match {
      case JsString(x) => LocalDateTime.parse(x, iso_date_time)
      case x => throw new RuntimeException(s"Unexpected type ${x.getClass.getName} when trying to parse LocalDateTime")
    }
  }
  // implicit val eventDataFormat: JsonFormat[SomeData] = jsonFormat1(SomeData) ** moved here **
}

object Main extends JsonSupport {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-system")
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
    implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher

    val route:Route =
      path("hello") {
        post {
          entity(as[SomeData]) { evt => complete(StatusCodes.Created) }
          }
      }

    val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)
    println(s"Server online at http://localhost:8080/\nPress RETURN to stop...")
    StdIn.readLine() // let it run until user presses return
    bindingFuture
      .flatMap(_.unbind()) // trigger unbinding from the port
      .onComplete(_ => system.terminate()) // and shutdown when done
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
implicit val eventDataFormat: JsonFormat[SomeData] = jsonFormat1(SomeData)
```

↓

```
implicit val eventDataFormat = jsonFormat1(SomeData)
```